# Formula versus Non-Formula Interface Categorical Variables train() glmnet

Tags: r, caret, glmnet, confusion-matrix

I am comparing the confusion matrix between the formula interface and the non-formula interface using caret's train() for elastic net. I am trying to understand why the two interfaces produces different confusion matrices. I understand that the formula interface will decompose the categorical variables into dummies and the model will have more coefficients.

First consider the formula interface model:

```
library(liver)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(dplyr)

data(churn)
head(churn)

set.seed(1)
train.index <- createDataPartition(churn$churn, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train_churn <- churn[train.index,]
test_churn  <- churn[-train.index,] 

# add class weights
my_weights = train_churn %>%
  select(churn) %>%
  group_by(churn) %>%
  count()

weight_for_yes = (1 / my_weights$n[1]) * ((my_weights$n[1] + my_weights$n[2]) / 2.0)
weight_for_yes
weight_for_no = (1 / my_weights$n[2]) * ((my_weights$n[1] + my_weights$n[2]) / 2.0)
weight_for_no

model_weights <- ifelse(train_churn$churn == "yes", weight_for_yes, weight_for_no)

myGrid <- expand.grid(
  alpha = 0, 
  lambda = 0.1  
)

#----------------- formula interface

set.seed(1)
mod_1 <- train(churn ~
                 state +
                 area.code +
                 intl.plan,
               data = train_churn,
               method = "glmnet",
               tuneGrid = myGrid,
               weights = model_weights)

prediction <- predict(mod_1, newdata = test_churn[,-20])
confusionMatrix(prediction, test_churn$churn)
```

[image]

Now consider the non-formula interface model:

```
#----------------- non-formula interface

predictors <- train_churn %>%
  select(state,
         area.code,
         intl.plan) %>%
  data.matrix()
response <- train_churn$churn

set.seed(1)
mod_2 <- train(x = predictors,
               y = response,
               method = "glmnet",
               tuneGrid = myGrid,
               weights = model_weights)
```

[image]

Is the disparity due to formula versus non-formula, or is this an artifact of elastic net?